# Setup Project Does Not Create File System Folders During Installation

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I want to create personal folders during installation. I did the following steps:

> Right click on your setup project ->
>   View -> File System
>
> Right click on node “File system on
>   target machine” -> Add special folder
>   -> User’s personal data folder
>
> Right click on node “User’s personal
>   data folder” -> Add -> Folder -> type
>   “My Personal Folder 1”
>
> After deployment they it should in
>   users “My documents”.

I know the above steps are correct and should work because i did it in the other application (solution) and worked fine. When i did same exact steps (of course i changed the folder name to be created), the application gets deployed but when i install, i don't get the Personal Folder under Documents? I wonder why did it work with my first solution and didn't work with the current one!

Please help, i have no other options except asking. I cleaned solution, i rebuilt, i tried different things but no hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some difference but there is no way we can find that.

Did you make sure there is no previous version installed?  Upped the versionnumber(s) ?

Comment: I installed the second application previously during the testing phase. However, i already uninstalled all previous versions, yet! The personal folder doesn't get created ... Odd

Comment: On the other hand, during the testing phase, everything worked fine, but after i made little tiny change in project setup properties, it didn't work at all no matter how i try.

Answer (score 3):

Use "always create" in the folder´s properties, otherwise it wont create empty folders during the installation